# My Wordpress Theme no have menu section

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm trying to development sample wordpress theme but when i choose my theme in admin panel. On appearance section i can't see MENUS section.

anybody now why?

Comment: Does going to `wp-admin/nav-menus.php` show the menu page?

Comment: I get this message when i try to open this link : Your theme does not support navigation menus or widgets.

Comment: Then that's your answer. Your theme doesn't support menus. You will need to either manually add links to the `header.php` or choose a theme that does allow menus

Comment: I made myself this theme. How can turn my theme to theme like does allow menus ?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)?

Answer (score -1):

Add in the following in function.php

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'Theme Name' ),    
    ) );
```